# Search a Json object array- List vs Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, json, list, dictionary

I deserialized a JsonResponse using the below code.

```
var data = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonResponse);
```

I got the response string which looks something like this

```
{  
   "results":[  
      {  
         "url":"tickets/2063.json",
         "id":20794,
         "subject":"Device not working",
         "created_date": "2018-01-10T13:03:23Z",
         "custom-fields":[  
            {  
               "id":25181002,
               "value":34534
            },
            {  
               "id":2518164,
               "value":252344
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

My objective is to read certain fields in this array of json objects and insert into a database. The fields i require are id, subject, created_date, member_id.

The member id is part of the custom fields. member_id is the value where id=2518164. I've used List to store this, can you let me know if List or Dictionary is better for this case. How to implement a dictionary

```
var data = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonResponse);
    var tickets = data["results"].ToList();
     foreach (var ticketItem in tickets){
        Int64? ticketFormId = ticketItem["id"].Value<Int64>();
        string subject = ticketItem["subject"].Value<string>();
        DateTime createdDate = ticketItem["created_date"].Value<DateTime>();

       //Do you think for the next step a dictionary is better or a List is better, since I want to search for a particular id=2518164
        var fieldsList = ticketItem["fields"].ToList();
        foreach(var fieldItem in fieldList){
            Int64? fieldId = fieldItem["id"].Value<Int64>();
            if(fieldId!=null && fieldId == 2518164){
                memberId = fieldItem["value"].Value<string>();
            }
        }
 }
```

Comment: Dictionary cannot have multiple entries with the same key value. In other words, if in your json data the Id is not unique, then you cannot use dictionary. By the way, you can merge those two lists into one, declared as List<Int64,string> too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your next step is to insert them all into the database, just store them into a list. A dictionary is only useful to search the item by a key.

You can also use Linq to process the JSON in a simpler way:

```
var tickets =   JObject.Parse(jsonResponse)["results"]
    .Select(ticket => new
    {
        Id = (long)ticket["id"],
        Subject = (string)ticket["subject"],
        CreatedDate = (DateTime)ticket["created_date"],
        MemberId = (long)ticket["custom-fields"]
            .FirstOrDefault(cf => (int)cf["id"] == 2518164)
            ?["value"],
    })
    .ToList();
```